# Further optimisation on swapping

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, computer-science

I was given a question in an interview to swap two variables for which I gave the following code:

```
package com.main;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int var1 = 6, var2 = 10;
        System.out.println("Before Swap var1 = "+var1+" and var2 = "+var2);
        int temp = var1;
        var1 = var2;
        var2 = temp;
        System.out.println("After Swap var1 = "+var1+" and var2 = "+var2);
    }

}
```

However the interviewer said it can be further optimised. It's time complexity is O(1) & space complexity is also O(1). what else can be optimised?

Comment: They're probably looking for the "clever" (pejoratively) solution `x = x^y; y = x^y; x = x^y;`. Note that this is terrible code. Yours is already O(1) and very easy to read, and works for any type. Ref: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_swap_algorithm. NEVER DO THIS in real code. Avoid companies that want you to do this in interviews. This is just clever code for the sake of being clever.

Comment: The way to optimise your code is... to let the JIT do it for you. Compilers are much better than you at micro-optimisation, and chances are if this part of the code is *really* a bottleneck, then both your solution and the interviewer's solution will get JITted to the same machine code anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing. The interviewer is an idiot.

They are looking for this. It's ridiculous that they are, and expecting interviewees to get this is idiotic, hence why I call them an idiot. I do not advise that you should ever write this in real code. I'm not going to suggest that you actively "do not know" a thing, because all knowledge is valuable, but given that you should never ever do this in real code, and the performance impact this will have is not something you'll ever be able to measure, the value of knowing this is extremely low:

```
var1 = var1 ^ var2;
var2 = var1 ^ var2;
var1 = var1 ^ var2;
```

this looks funky as all get out, but try it and you'll find that it 'works'.

In practice, if anything, it's probably *slower* than what you wrote, but explaining why requires a year of studying how CPUs and pipelines work.

Explaining why the above works, well, search the web for what bitwise XOR does (`^` is bitwise XOR in java), pick some example numbers, say, 4 and 5, and give it a shot. Just go through it step by step. Or search the web for the explanation, plenty of blogposts explaining this exotic cornercase.